# dhcpd doesn't issue the same lease after reboot

Tags: linux, networking, embedded-linux

I am running 4.14.149 built by Yocto (Zeus, 3.0.0), and we are pulling the OpenEmbedded version of dhcpd (I think it is version 4.4.1).

Here is my conf file:

```
#
# DHCPd config for private network
#

# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
ddns-update-style none;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
log-facility local7;

# Set the lease time to 6 hours so the 'dhcp.leases' file grows slowly
default-lease-time 21600;
max-lease-time 21600;

# This is a very basic subnet declaration. Address .201 and above can be used
# for static IP assignment
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.200;
}
```

What I am seeing is that if I connect another board to it, it properly gets an IP address.  But if I reboot the attached device, it gets a different IP address.  If I look in the leases file, I am noticing the UID is different, even though it is the exact same device:

```
root@alvaFHABeeprom:~# cat /var/lib/dhcp-private/dhcpd.leases
# The format of this file is documented in the dhcpd.leases(5) manual page.
# This lease file was written by isc-dhcp-4.4.1

# authoring-byte-order entry is generated, DO NOT DELETE
authoring-byte-order little-endian;

server-duid "\000\001\000\001'\221\321\015\002\220\233n\366\303";

lease 10.0.0.2 {
  starts 3 2021/01/13 15:43:02;
  ends 3 2021/01/13 21:43:02;
  cltt 3 2021/01/13 15:43:02;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:0a:55:02:27:3e;
  uid "\377(\376\362\321\000\002\000\000\253\021d~N\310\030\210G\356";
  client-hostname "alva-UI";
}
lease 10.0.0.3 {
  starts 3 2021/01/13 15:44:13;
  ends 3 2021/01/13 21:44:13;
  cltt 3 2021/01/13 15:44:13;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:0a:55:02:27:3e;
  uid "\377(\376\362\321\000\002\000\000\253\021tl\350s\205\3666E";
  client-hostname "alva-UI";
}
root@alvaFHABeeprom:~#
```

How do I get the exact same device to have the same address after reboot?  I have tried adding `one-lease-per-client true;` to my dhcpd configuration, but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `uid` (DHCP Client Identifier) seems to be generated by the *systemd-networkd* DHCP client:

```
\377(\376\362\321\000\002\000\000\253\021tl\350s\205\3666E
```

| byte | value |
| --- | --- |
| `\377` | DHCP client ID type: N/A (255) – contains RFC 4361 embedded DHCPv6 IAID+DUID |
| `(\376\362\321` | DHCPv6 IAID: `28:FE:F2:D1` |
| `\000\002` | DHCPv6 DUID type: DUID-EN (2) – vendor specific |
| `\000\000\253\021` | DUID-EN private enterprise number: systemd (43793) |
| `d~N\310\030\210G\356` | DUID-EN vendor-specific data: `64:7E:4E:C8:18:88:47:EE` |

In systemd-networkd, the DHCPv6 DUID-EN (and consequently, the DHCP client identifier) is generated by hashing the 128-bit ID stored in the [machine-id](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html) file. If this file is missing and `/etc` is read-only, a different ID will be generated on each boot (by the *systemd-machine-id-setup* service).

Ideally this file should persist across reboots – if your /etc is on a read-only filesystem, symlink the file to /var or another persistent location.

An easier fix, but one that only applies to DHCP, is to configure the client to generate its DHCP client identifier from MAC address instead:

```
[DHCPv4]
# This disables DHCPv6 DUID usage in DHCPv4 completely, and uses
# the traditional client ID type 0x01 (Ethernet MAC address).
ClientIdentifier=mac

[DHCPv6]
DUIDType=link-layer
```

It is not recommended to ignore client IDs in your DHCP server.

Comment: We do store our other network settings on a user data partition.  I am trying to create a link to that area now.  Perhaps this should be a separate question, but I am trying to make the link in our `base-files_%.bbappend` the same way we do the `hostname` file, but it appears that there are other things that touch that file that are failing (I see it touched in in the `rootfs-postcommands.bbclass` for example).  Is there a recommended way to create that link?

Answer (score 0):

So I can't explain why the UID is different every boot, but adding `ignore-client-uids true;` to my config fixed it.

Unfortunately I found this after I posted this question, but this is the solution outlined in: https://serverfault.com/questions/694351/how-do-i-keep-isc-dhcpd-from-offering-different-ips-when-there-is-two-requests-f

Comment: Do your clients have persistent storage? This looks like they're forgetting their /etc/machine-id.

Comment: We do have persistent storage, but we are using a read-only filesystem, and a quick google suggests that file is generated on first boot.  Since that file can't be saved due to the read only FS, it appears in my case that file is generated every boot.  Would you recommend I find a way to keep that file persistent or just ignore the UID as outlined above?

Comment: If the entire FS is read-only, that's kind of the opposite of having persistent storage... Ideally the file should be persistent (e.g. a symlink to a file in /var), but if that's not possible, configure systemd-networkd to use MAC-address-based DHCP client identifiers instead.